# Last inserted Id returning null

Tags: php

I am trying to return Last Inserted ID after successful insertion. I have read and search lot of thread but still I am not getting what I am looking for. In my return array last_inserted_id:null,. I know I am not doing something right here.

This is my includes/DbOperation.php

```
class DbConnect
{
    private $conn;

    function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Establishing database connection
     * @return database connection handler
     */
    function connect()
    {
        require_once 'Constants.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

        // Check for database connection error
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        // returing connection resource
        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

This is my method

```
   //Function to add delivery address
    public function addDeliveryAddress($recipientName, $recipientPhoneNumber, $recipientArea, $recipientAddress, $nearestLandmark, $userId)
    {
        try{ $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO deliveryAddressTbl (recipientName, recipientPhoneNumber, recipientArea, recipientAddress, nearestLandmark, userId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $recipientName, $recipientPhoneNumber, $recipientArea, $recipientAddress, $nearestLandmark, $userId);

            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                //return DELIVERY_ADDRESS_ADDED_SUCCESSFULLY;

                $result = $stmt->insert_id;
                $stmt->close();
                return $result;
            } else {
                return DELIVERY_ADDRESS_COULDNOT_BE_ADDED;
            }
        }
        catch (PDOExeception $e){
            echo $e;
        }

    }
```

And this is my Index page

```
<?php

//importing required script
require_once 'includes/DbOperation.php';

$response = array();
//print array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    //getting values
    $recipientName = $_POST['recipientName'];
    $recipientPhoneNumber = $_POST['recipientPhoneNumber'];
    $recipientArea = $_POST['recipientArea'];
    $recipientAddress = $_POST['recipientAddress'];
    $nearestLandmark = $_POST['nearestLandmark'];
    $userId = $_POST['userId'];

    //creating db operation object
    $db = new DbOperation();

    //adding address to database
    $result = $db->addDeliveryAddress($recipientName, $recipientPhoneNumber, $recipientArea, $recipientAddress, $nearestLandmark, $userId );

    //making the response accordingly
    if ($result != DELIVERY_ADDRESS_COULDNOT_BE_ADDED) {

        $response['error'] = false;
        $response["last_inserted_id"] = $deliveryId;
        $response['message'] = 'Delivery address added successfully';

    } elseif ($result == DELIVERY_ADDRESS_COULDNOT_BE_ADDED) {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'Delivery address counldnot be added';
    } 

} else {
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Invalid Request!';
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

thanks all

Comment: You have `bind_param` and tagged as "mysqli", yet you have an `PDOExeception` which is PDO; two different animals here. Now, if you don't have an auto_increment'ed column, then last_insert can't work without it.

Comment: There is no code that sets `$deliveryId`, which could be why it's null

Comment: Lets start by clearing up which Database Extension you are actually using to connect to the database. **Please** show us the `includes/DbOperation.php` code

Comment: Voting this as a potential typographical error; I'm out (same as the OP). I love "communication", *don't you?*

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have edited and added my includes/DbOperation.php

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I have an an auto_increment'ed column that is why I am trying to get the last_insert

Comment: @SamuelSam how are you setting `$deliveryId`?

Comment: @ChrisLear.. yes my bad.. I was trying to get Last result id from the wrong variable not response.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last result id is saved in $result but you are trying to get the value from $deliveryId which is null and never set please try change the variable form $deliveryId to $result while saving in response.

```
$result = $db->addDeliveryAddress($recipientName, $recipientPhoneNumber, $recipientArea, $recipientAddress, $nearestLandmark, $userId );

        //making the response accordingly
        if ($result != DELIVERY_ADDRESS_COULDNOT_BE_ADDED) {

            $response['error'] = false;
            //$response["last_inserted_id"] = $deliveryId;
              $response["last_inserted_id"] = $result;
```

Comment: This has been downvoted twice, but looks quite sane to me

Comment: I have changed the response from $response["last_inserted_id"] = $deliveryId; to              $response["last_inserted_id"] = $result;

Comment: $response["last_inserted_id"] = $result; is correct thanks

Comment: A bit worrying that this got downvoted by two different people, when it was the right answer all along.